# Does this sum converge, is my solution good?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)^{7}}{(n^{7}+1)^{1/2}} $$

I would say that it doesn't converge, cause I would  write this as:
$$  $$

$$ \frac{\sin(n)^{7}}{(n^{7})^{1/2}} $$ when  $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} $$
then I would write this as:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)^{7}}{(n^{7})*n^{1/2}}$$
and then I would say that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)^{7}}{(n^{7})^{1/2}} $$ converges , but that the 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} $$

doesn't converge, so overall sum doesn't converge.

Comment: It definitely converges - it is bounded above by $\sum\frac 1{n^2}$

Comment: Might be better to say $|(\sin n^7)/(n^7+1)^{1/2}| \le 1/n^2,$ etc.

Answer (score 9):

The sum converges because $\sin(n)\leq 1$, so 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigl| \frac{\sin^7(n)}{(n^7+1)^{1/2}} \Bigr| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^7+1)^{1/2}} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^7)^{1/2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{7/2}} 
\end{equation}
The last series converges, so the given series converges absolutely. Absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: You really need absolute values on that first series.

Comment: You're right, zhw. I"ve corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are not applying well the properties of the exponentials. Instead, you can write:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg| \frac{\sin(n)^7}{(n^7)^{1/2}}\Bigg| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{7/2}} <\infty,$$
since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}<\infty
$$
if and only if $\alpha>1$.